# Send supertype as type information in Kafka JSON Serialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot to send data from one application to the other using Kafka.

My design uses an interface to declare the data being sent:

```
package domain;

interface Data {
    public String getData();
    public void setData(String data);
}
```

**Producer**

In the source app, I implement this interface as a db Entity.

```
package persistence;

@Data
class DataEntity implements Data {
    private String data;  // lombok generates getter/setters
}
```

When an entity is added, I want send it as an update to Kafka using the KafkaTemplate

```
@Component
class DataPublisher implements ApplicationListener<DataEvent> {
    @Autowired private KafkaTemplate<String,Data> template;

    // I left out DataEvent which is a straightforward ApplicationEvent override
    @EventListener(classes = DataEvent.class)
    public void onApplicationEvent(DataEvent event) {
        template.send("data", (Data) event.getSource());
    }
}
// triggered by this call in a service
    eventPublisher.publishEvent(new DataEvent(updatedData));
```

The serialization is done via the properties

```
spring:
    kafka:
        consumer:
            value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
            properties.spring.json.value.default.type: domain.Data
```

Looking at kafkacat output, the data is sent fine.

**Consumer**

On the receiving side I have

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "data")
public void dataUpdated(@Payload Data data) {
    dataService.updateData(data);
}
```

which results in

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'persistence.DataEntity' is not in the trusted packages [...]

which I understand perfectly fine - the serializer sends a `persistence.DataEntity` object, but the client expects a `domain.Data` object. But that's how the design is supposed to be; I want the client to only know about the domain package, not its `persistence` implementation. (As a side question, where can I see this type header? It's not in the encoded json AFAICT, what am I missing?)

So the question is: how do I force the Spring `JsonDeserializer` to send `domain.Data` as the serialized data type?

I did find a TYPE_MAPPING property in the serializer class, but its only documentation is that it "add[s] type mappings to the type mapper: 'foo:com.Foo,bar:com.Bar'" which doesn't explain anything and I can't find an example usage.

EDIT:

I did add

> spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=domain.Data:persistence.DataEntity

to the properties of the producer, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types).

You have to provide mapping on both sides.

However, instead of using the `JsonDeserializer`, you should use a `BytesDeserializer` and a `BytesJsonMessageConverter` (simply add one as a `@Bean` and Boot will wire it into the container factory).

That way, the framework will automatically convert to the parameter type.

Again, see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#spring-messaging-message-conversion).

Comment: I did read that part as well, but still didn't entirely get it. So I use the token as a representative and map it to different types on each side? I'll try it out when I get back to my machine.

Comment: OK, so I did add `spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=data:persistence.DataEntity` to the producer and `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=data:domain.Data` to the consumer, but I still get "The class 'persistence.DataEntity' is not in the trusted packages" on the consumer side.

Comment: Right; you have to add the package to the deserializer's trusted packages as well. It's to protect you from malicious behavior.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to deserialize as `domain.Data`, and `domain` _is_ in the trusted packages. Why does it even mention the `persistence` package? I'd assume it would never reach the consumer now that I've used a token for that type.

Comment: It looks like your mappings are not being applied somehow; either run it in a debugger to figure out why, or post a small sample app that exhibits the behavior. There's a [test case here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainerTests.java#L1711-L1740) that shows it works.

Comment: looks like a versioning problem, the apps I'm working on are depending on `spring-kafka:2.1.8`, and AFAICT you checked in the type mapping with 2.2. Just upgrading `spring-kafka` doesn't seem to work for those projects, I'll have try another way; thanks a lot though.

Comment: is there any chance to set ```BytesJsonMessageConverter ``` via properties, since anything else could be set via properties ;D

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments. No; you have to add a `@Bean`.